# URL Session not able to delay till execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url

I'm requesting an URL session but before getting data from URL my program goes on executing without getting data which is giving me an error.
So how do I delay the execution until the session is over or how to execute session and then carry on with code?

```
- (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender{
if(_otptf.text==self.otpStr && _otptf.text>0){
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@,otp=%@",self.stri1,self.stri];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sitesandflats.com/otp_verify.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
    //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                       userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
        //   NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
        NSLog(@"Req:%@",requestReply);
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
        self.tmpv=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"sucess"] ;
        self.strv=self.tmpv;
        NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmpv);
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                         target: self
                                       selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                       userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
    }] resume];
   // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:<#(nonnull NSString *)#> sender:<#(nullable id)#>]
   //[self stats];
   // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                     target: self
                                   selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                   userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
      //  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b2" sender:self];
    [self stats];
    //});
}
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions!!

Comment: Put code in session's `completionHandler ` to execute after the session end? what's the real question here?

Comment: the program is not going inside sessions block

Comment: so how to wait till the session gives me a reply??@Tj3n

Comment: The code inside `completionHandler ` will start once it retrieved the response from your API

Comment: so what do you suggest I should use there??@Tj3n

Comment: what is the use of two timers here as well as what the use of [self stats];

Comment: no timers worked actually I was trying out some way and self stats contain segue to move to next page@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: actually I mailed u morn today@Anbu.Karthik if you can check wen u have time

Comment: and is it ok to have two or more url sessions in same file?@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Please learn how to ask question properly. I can't understand what you want.

Comment: asynchronous url session...how to change the code so that the url session gets completed then the other remaining part should execute!!!I wanted to find a way for that@GeneCode

Comment: The urlsession code you have above is fine. All the code inside the block completionHandler:^() { ... } will only be executed after server returns a reply to your app.

Comment: I want the session block to execute first my following codes depend on the reply from the server and here comes the prob!!!so can u suggest me some ideas???@GeneCode

Comment: adding exclamation marks to your question doesn't help. seriously I can't understand what is your problem. hopefully someone else can help you. have a nice day.